# How to know if any website is using Google Website optimizer for A/B testing?

Tags: google-analytics, usability, a-b-testing, google-website-optimizer

How to know if any website is using Google Website optimizer for A/B testing? By viewing a source code. For what to look into view source which confirms that site is using Google Website optimizer

Answer (score 2):

Look for the _utmx cookie for the site in question.

From [Google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsCookies)

> You can use Google Analytics with Google Website Optimizer (GWO), which is a tool that helps determine the most effective design for your site. When a website optimizer script executes on your page, a _utmx cookie is written to the browser and its value is sent to Google Analytics. See the Website Optimizer Help Center for more information.

Comment: NO _utmx in source code of website

Comment: And only these cookies are showing http://i.imgur.com/arEii.jpg no _utmx

Comment: It's possible they are using a different testing system like phpabtest or any of the many others.